# uwsgi + wkhtmltopdf + Django not works

Tags: python, django, nginx, wkhtmltopdf, uwsgi

I create a deployment of Django application with nginx and uwsgi. Where I try access to page rendered in pdf with wkhtmltopdf print the following error:

> Command '['wkhtmltopdf', '--encoding', u'utf8', '--quiet', '/tmp/wkhtmltopdfQuoAXk.html', '-']' returned non-zero exit status 1

I think that wkhtmltopdf can't create the pdf, because the uwsgi request is not parse with HTML directly.

Do you think?

Comment: Is that working on your local dev server?

Comment: No, I'm working a vps server with Ubuntu 12.04 Server

Comment: I haven't used wkhtmltopdf but there are some people with the same issue (https://github.com/incuna/django-wkhtmltopdf/issues/67). Are your static files reachable?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem with help of this comment: https://github.com/incuna/django-wkhtmltopdf/issues/67#issuecomment-120930906

I changed in Django the STATIC_URL by default to:

```
STATIC_URL = 'http://domain.com/static/'
```

And I use "static" in templates as recommended the official documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/:

`{% load staticfiles %}` and
`{% static 'js/jquery.min.js'%}"`